# how to work around the warning of scipy csc-matrix about index pointer should start with 0 in a for loop?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

We have analysed a big dataset and saved the data as [csc sparse array](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SparseArrays/) in Julia language, and then I tried to load the array in python language using scipy's [csc_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html). However, my PC is not big enough RAM to process the data (I saw the warning: unable to allocate 93.gib for an array with shape).

Hence, I was hoping to process this data as small portions under a for-loop.

```
def get_jld(filename):
    orient_list=[]
    ID_num=999
    f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
    data= f["sm"][()]

    column_ptr=f[data[2]][:]-1 ## correct indexing from julia (starts at 1)
    indices=f[data[3]][:]-1 ## correct indexing
    values =f[data[4]][:]
    for i in range(0, data[1], ID_num):
        out = pd.DataFrame(csc_matrix((values,indices,column_ptr[i:i+ID_num+1]), shape=(data[0],ID_num)).toarray())
        orient_angle=find_orientation(out)
        orient_list.append(orient_angle)
    f.close()
return orient_list
```

However, csc_matrix sent a warning saying "index pointer should start with 0", which means whenever I reach to the second iteration of this loop, csc_matrix will stop (without looping through the entire sparse array).

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

Cell In[6], line 2
      1 filename=vid_list[0]
----> 2 test = get_jld(filename)

Cell In[3], line 13, in get_jld(filename)
     10 #indices[indices < time_start] = time_start
     11 #print([data[0],data[1]])
     12 for i in range(0, data[1], ID_num):
---> 13     out =pd.DataFrame(csc_matrix((values,indices,column_ptr[i:i+ID_num+1]), shape=(data[0],ID_num)).toarray())
     14     orient_angle=find_orientation(out)
     15     orient_list.append(orient_angle)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\qlm_analysis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_compressed.py:106, in _cs_matrix.__init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
    103 if dtype is not None:
    104     self.data = self.data.astype(dtype, copy=False)
--> 106 self.check_format(full_check=False)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\qlm_analysis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_compressed.py:172, in _cs_matrix.check_format(self, full_check)
    169     raise ValueError("index pointer size ({}) should be ({})"
    170                      "".format(len(self.indptr), major_dim + 1))
    171 if (self.indptr[0] != 0):
--> 172     raise ValueError("index pointer should start with 0")
    174 # check index and data arrays
    175 if (len(self.indices) != len(self.data)):

ValueError: index pointer should start with 0
```

Does anyone has any suggestion to work around this issue?

Comment: We don't like images of code and errors.  I can read it, but I can't copy-n-paste code into answer.  So over all make it harder to help you.

Comment: Working a meory of looking t the image earlier, the problem line is too long - `pd.Dataframe(sparse.csc_matrix(...).toarray())`.  That `toarray` step could produce a memory error, since a dense array takes up much more memory than sparse.

Comment: Looks like you take the `data,indices,indptr` values from one matrix, and try to make a new one.  And the values you select for `indptr` are bad.  Making a matrix with this style of input requires good understanding of those arrays; it is close to being the 'raw' input for a `csc`.  You can't fudge the values.  I won't try to create a working example or correct your image code.

Comment: Make a matrix like `sparse.random(10,10, .2, 'csc')`, ie some `csc` matrix. and look at the attributes, especially the `indptr`.  Note how that starts [0, n1, n2, n3...]` and ends.  That arrays says where each column's `indices` and `data` start (and end).  You can't make a subset of another matrix by just grabbing a subset of its attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and comment. I have re-formatted my codes and error message. Also you were right about my intention, I was hoping to make a subset of another matrix by just grabbing a subset of its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make a csc matrix (10x10 with .2 desity)

```
In [68]: from scipy import sparse

In [69]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.2, 'csc'); M
Out[69]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

The key attributes are:

```
In [71]: M.data, M.indices, M.indptr
Out[71]: 
(array([0.56697998, 0.53160297, 0.69832231, 0.54057255, 0.86921503,
        0.15293358, 0.51262743, 0.52701144, 0.52747434, 0.32865321,
        0.01983809, 0.59817796, 0.24101313, 0.17601203, 0.04915645,
        0.74543831, 0.62962088, 0.69383003, 0.45157457, 0.31947605]),
 array([9, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 6, 9, 6, 0, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2, 5, 9, 5, 0, 3]),
 array([ 0,  1,  6,  6,  8,  9, 14, 17, 18, 18, 20]))
```

From that I can read that the first column has one nonero value at row 9 - the first element in `data`:

```
In [72]: M[9,0]
Out[72]: 0.5669799764654442
```

Similarly the last `data` element is column 9, and row 3 (last value of `indices`):

```
In [73]: M[3,9]
Out[73]: 0.3194760497137821
```

`indptr` starts with 0, and has 11 elements.  The `indptr` values tell us/python how to split up the `data` and `indices` values into successive columns.

So if making a matrix from 'raw' values, thay to match this pattern.

Usually it is easier to create a matrix from `coo` style inputs, but if starting from some other `csc` matrix, or if you know what you doing, it is posible to use this 'raw' input.  It's faster, but also easier to mess up.

I haven't looked again are your images, but I think you are string with a large csc, and trying to make smaller csc from a subset of its `data/indices/indptr`.  I haven't tried to do that myself, so I don't know what adjustements you have to take to do it right.

(I usually work with csr format, so I had to mentally switch the desciption to csc.)